# When not to use rref for finding eigenvectors?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this matrix which is corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda = 50$:
\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
 27 & 0 & 36&0\\
0&0&0&0 \\  
 36 & 0& -27&0  
\end{array}
The eigenvectors for $\lambda$ are $(0, 1, 0)^T$ and $(1, 0, \frac{4}{3})^T$. But when I transform the matrix into reduced row echelon form I get:
\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
 1 & 0 & -7&0\\
0&0&1&0 \\  
 0 & 0& 0&0  
\end{array}
which results only in the form $(0,a,0)^T$.

How do I see initially, that I can't use rref for finding eigenvectors?

Comment: Neither of the vectors you gave are eigenvectors of the given matrix corresponding to an eigenvalue of $50$. Is the matrix you gave supposed to be $A$ or $A- 50 I$? Even in the latter case something is wrong, please check your problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're "finding the rref of a matrix", you're changing the matrix by applying row-operations.  That is, you're multiplying on the left by an invertible matrix.

Now, suppose that $A$ has an eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, and suppose we've row reduced $A$ to the matrix $EA$, where $E$ is some invertible matrix.  We then have
$$
(EA)v = E(Av) = E (\lambda v) = \lambda Ev
$$
so, whether $v$ is once more an eigenvector depends very much on the sequence of row-operations applied.

We also might not even have the same eigenvalues.