# Gaussian Elimination and Eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gaussian-elimination

I've read in many places that Gaussian Elimination cannot be used to find the eigenvectors of a matrix. I don't understand why.

Assume we have the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and we know the eigenvalues $\lambda$. As far as I know:

1. The eigenspace corresponding to a given eigenvalue is the nullspace of the matrix $\mathbf{A-\lambda\,\mathbf{I}}$
2. Gaussian elimination preserves the nullspace of a matrix

Given that these statements are correct (please correct me if I'm wrong) doesn't it mean that if I apply GE on $\mathbf{A-\lambda\,\mathbf{I}}$, the resulting reduced matrix must have the same nullspace as that of $\mathbf{A-\lambda\,\mathbf{I}}$ and, hence, gives the same set of eigenvectors?

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you give an example of a place you read this?

Comment: For example here: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306406/when-not-to-use-rref-for-finding-eigenvectors). Not in textbooks though. Could the initial statement be wrong then and, in fact, GE can be used to find the eigenvectors?